# Fastest way to make sure arp -n contains router

Tags: networking, arp

My goal is to get the mac adres of my router. I have a manufacturer id where I filter on e.g. always starts with c0:c0:c0 so I use:

```
arp -n | grep -i 'c0:c0:c0'
```

This works fine:
However when the system just booted and no netwerktraffic occured arp does not contain the route. I can 'add' it by using

```
ping google.com
```

or pinging te gateway, after this action arp contains the router.
What is the fastest/best way to make sure arp contains the router?

edit:

So far the fastest solution (without having to know my gateway) is:

```
ping -c 1 -W 1 192.168.1.1 && arp -n ; grep -i 'c0:c0:c0'
```

Comment: The ARP cache is only updated when the ARP cache does not contain an ARP record for the given requested IP(s).  Short of statically adding ARP routes (which is dangerous unless you really know what you're doing, because it could break your network) the only way would be to ping the router on boot.  because the first thing your computer will do is send an ARP request over the network saying "Who has [gw address]?  Tell [computer IP]." then gets a reply and updates its internal arp table.

Comment: @ThomasWard What happens if I just ping a website, lets say i do not want to find my gateway address first. If the website is not found the gateway is still discovered and added to the arp table right?

Answer (score 1):

You already are assuming you know what your gw is (192.168.1.1) but as the question is posed, I understand that may not be the case.

I'd make sure first using "ip route", then something like:

```
$ ping -c1 -W1 $(ip route | grep default | awk '{print $3}')
```

I don't understand what you gain with don't knowing your gw first. Your system already know it, otherwise it couldn't ping anywhere.